# SQL Server - Override DELETE command?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a situation where I want my Azure MS SQL Server DB Table (or entire DB if needed) to ignore Delete commands it receives from a remote source.

Is there a way to override the delete command default functionality to essentially take the request and send back a success message?

I want to do this so I can have a one way synchronization that keeps deleted records as an archive since the master database that will be sharing the transnational updates will be purged regularly.

Comment: If you don't want to delete rows in the database, why are you issuing delete statements against it?

Comment: I am using a service that does a really great job of sharing Inserts and Updates that I want to capture. It also includes Deletes which I don't want to process. I asked if it was possible to disable issuing the Deletes however this is unfortunately not possible with the service at this time.

Since it is ideal in every other way I'm hopeful that a small modification like the one suggested by Marc will allow me to use the service without replicating the Delete commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can set a INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger, which replaces the standard actions for DELETE commands with your code (in this case it would be an empty code, so it does nothing when someone tries to delete records from that table).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. So far on initial tests it appears to work perfectly.